# D3js transition between two path cause parsing error

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I try to make a simple transition / interpolation between two path / shapes (designed in illustrator).

I have d3 in my project, so I use it; but I could try something else if I can figure out how to do.

I Define a few variables (including the two path) :

```
    var width = 300,
        height = 300;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var path = svg.append("path"),
        d0 = "M12,2c5.514,0,10,4.486,10,10c0,5.514-4.486,10-10,10C6.486,22,2,17.514,2,12C2,6.486,6.486,2,12,2z M12,0 C5.372,0,0,5.372,0,12c0,6.629,5.372,12,12,12s12-5.371,12-12C24,5.372,18.628,0,12,0z",
        d1 = "M12,19.938c5.514,0,10-13.452,10-7.938c0,5.514-4.486,10-10,10C6.486,22,2,17.514,2,12C2,6.486,6.486,19.938,12,19.938z M12,0C5.372,0,0,5.372,0,12c0,6.629,5.372,12,12,12s12-5.371,12-12C24,5.372,18.628,0,12,0z";
```

Then I start to loop on the transition :

```
    loop();

    function loop() {
        path
            .attr("d", d0)
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .attr("d", d1)
            .transition()
            .delay(5000)
            .attr("d", d0)
            .each("end", loop);
    }
```

And the weird things happen !

I have a long list of errors in my console : `Error: Problem parsing d="M12,10.9402992c5.514,0,10-4.4542992,101.0597007999999999c0,5.514-4.486,10-10,10C6.486,22,2,17.514,2,12C2,6.486,6.486,10.9402992,12,10.9402992z M12,0C5.372,0,0,5.372,0,12c0,6.629,5.372,12,12,12s12-5.371,12-12C24,5.372,18.628,0,12,0z"`

Which is not a valid svg. As far as I understand what this is about, svg path with float numbers are non valid (but I do have floats in my base path and they work ; so I'm not so sure).

It appears that I should try to round all the numbers all along the transition.

But the fact I really don't understand is why it works on the last 75% of the loop and not on the first 25%.

Here is a fiddle to see the fail in action : http://jsfiddle.net/vQabH/

And why it works on this one : http://jsfiddle.net/9bC6M/
(which I made from this example : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your paths, negative values are not separated by space or comma. For example, there is `c5.514,0,10,4.486,10,10` (3 pairs of values, separated by comma), but `c0,5.514-4.486,10-10,10` (again 3 pairs of values, but not all separated with commas). This messes up the D3 transition.

D3 simply doesn't know how to interpolate between strings like that. For example, you're getting a parse error for `c5.514,0,10-4.4542992,101.0597007999999999` (2 pairs of values and a spurious number).

It works fine when you separate the negative values from the rest, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vQabH/1/). Technically, you could argue that it should still work as it's a valid SVG path, so you may want to open an issue about this on the D3 website.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your solution :) I'll try to add an issue, D3 should manage it. (or at least reparse the svg)